# Play a video on a TV over HDMI without DEX experience

Tags: samsung, samsung-dex

I see there are two options on how to connect my S9 to a TV over HDMI: dex and screen mirroring. Neither of them quite fits what I want to do.
I'm coming from the iPhone and I want to do the same as there - use a tv only when a video is playing. E.g. I'm browsing web on my phone as usual but once I start a video I have a choice where to run it on the local phone screen or on the connected screen.

Full dex experience is just too much hassle and looks like overkill for this, not all the apps support it and sometimes there are minor issues with fullscreen players. While screen mirroring is even worse, works only with phone display on and adds black bars twice horizontally and vertically, I believe it's because screen ratio of S9 does not match my TV screen ratio 16:9

Comment: On Android the common way to play a video on a TV  is using Google Chromecast. Direct connections via USB/MHL/HDMI are not available on every device therefore the support is not standardized and hence not tested/considered by every app developer.

Comment: @Robert so does it support scenario I described? Or will it be only screen mirroring again?

Comment: The video stream only is transmitted only, if the sending app supports the Google Cast protocol. Otherwise only screen mirroring is used. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cast) for details.